# dot3StatsDuplexStatus not firing from Cisco Switch

Tags: cisco, ios, snmp, oid

Anyone have any luck with this Trap dot3StatsDuplexStatus OID = 1.3.6.1.2.1.10.7.2.1.19

I am able to test the OID by doing an SNMP walk which shows the correct information, however no Traps are ever fired for this?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

I was informed by Cisco Community that it is because this is not a TRAP type OID.